# Compute the number of permutation functions $f : \{1,\ldots,n\} \mapsto \{1,\ldots,n\} !$

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, permutations

A excercise from abstract algebra class. But I don't know why there is factorial sign put outside the bracket. Does it represent anything?

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say $\text{“}f : \{1,\ldots,n\} \to \{1,\ldots,n\} !\text{''}$ rather than $\text{“}f : \{1,\ldots,n\} \mapsto \{1,\ldots,n\} !\text{''} \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: It is indeed ↦ (mapping) , not → .